# Why does the python script finish before it gets the results from java if executed through cron job?

Tags: java, python, jar, cron

I need to run a jar file that I don't have access to modify through a python script.

If I run the python script manually it works fine, but if I run it through a cron job, it finishes without executing the jar file
I'm using the following python code to run the java jar:

```
os.system('java -jar jar_file.jar > output.txt')
```

I also tried:

```
os.system('/usr/local/jdk/bin/java -jar jar_file.jar > output.txt')
```

After that I need to read the data from the `output.txt` file using the same python script.

In the crontab I have the task set as:

```
*/30 * * * * (cd /path/to/python/script && exec /usr/bin/python script.py)
```

If I run the script manually I get data in the output file, but if I run the script through the cron job, I get an empty `output.txt` file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cron jobs have different environment. Some PATHs etc. might be missing. Just guessing, but this should be the first thing to check.

Comment: cronjob may run as different user with different privillages. BTW: use fullpath even for `.jar` file.

Comment: @VPfB It was, indeed, related to the environment variables. I got that fixed then came here to post the answer. If your comment was an answer I'd choose it to be the correct answer. Feel free to post it as an answer if you want to.

Comment: @XO39 I'm glad I could help. That's all from me. One item from a checklist is not going to be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the cron job environment, after posting the question I did some tests and checked the log, found out that it doesn't load all the needed path variables, as soon as I loaded all the needed variables, it worked.